# OS X getting remote process input args sometimes fails

Tags: c++, macos, ps, sysctl

i would like to retrieve remote process input arguments programmatically,
so i used sysctl in the following manner (partial code) :

```
int    mib[3]
mib = {CTL_KERN, KERN_ARGMAX,0,0}

size = sizeof(argmax);
if (sysctl(mib, 2, &argmax, &size, NULL, 0) == -1) {
    goto ERROR_A;
}
procargs = (char *)malloc(argmax);

mib = {CTL_KERN,KERN_PROCARGS2,pid,0}

size = (size_t)argmax;
if (sysctl(mib, 3, procargs, &size, NULL, 0) == -1) {
    printf("a");
    goto ERROR_B;
}
```

however, i doesn't work for all processes. 
here's is a working case :

/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Versions/A/Support/mdworker -s mdworker -c MDSImporterWorker -m com.apple.mdworker.shared

but the case below failed on "sysctl(mib, 3, procargs, &size, NULL, 0)".
although, i successfully got the command line using 'ps ax PID' from terminal

```
0   655   501   0 10:55AM ttys008    0:00.02 login -pfl zohar81 /bin/bash -c exec -la bash /bin/bash
```

perhaps you can tell me why calling sysctl with KERN_PROCARGS2 failed in the second example ?

thanks

Comment: Generally reading process args requires elevated permissions (eg.  root), and the code would need to be owned by whoever is running it.

Comment: that's right ! thanks for your help, i was mistakably running my code without root permission. i guess 'ps' runs on root permissions by default.

Comment: Since you're running `ps` from a what is likely a bash login shell your user already has the necessary permissions to execute the command.

Comment: i had the same problem yesterday and it bugged me for hours so i thought i could answer this question even if i'm late :)

Comment: @l'L'l Honestly I don't see why you should have such permissions. You can always spawn a child and execute the ps command through the bash and get the result. So in my opinion this just made to create problems to a developer. For other OSs this restriction doesn't applies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that on OS X, the process is granted access to KERN_PROCARGS2 for all processes when the owner of the executable is root and the the executable has the SUID (set-uid) flag enabled. The only exception is PID 0 (kernel_task) but that doesn't even have arguments.

You can make this work for your file using:

```
chmod u+s myprogram
sudo chown root:wheel myprogram
# now my program should be able to make get KERN_PROCARGS2 for all processes
./myprogram
```

Comment: If I try to run this on a executable based of a __NSApplication__ i get this error:  _"The application with bundle ID x.y.z is running setugid(), which is not allowed. Exiting."_